# How to check if custom culture exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, cultureinfo, culture

I have created one custom culture as 'gh-es'. I am trying to check if its already registered.its working fine if culture is registered but if not it throw an error in start only.

I am unable to find how to check if a culture is present or to check if its exists

```
  $CustomCulture= [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('gh-es')
    If($CustomCulture -ne null)
       {
          Write-output "culture already registered"
         }
     Else
          {
             $CultureName = 'gh-es' 
                  $BaseCulture=[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('es-US') 
    $BaseRegion = New-Object System.Globalization.RegionInfo 'es-US' 
try {

# Set up CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder 
Add-Type -AssemblyName sysglobl
        
$CultureBuilder = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder 
          @($CultureName,[System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionModifiers]::None) $CultureBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo($BaseCulture)
             $CultureBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo($BaseRegion)
             $CultureBuilder.Register()
                     } 
                    catch
                     {
                     throw
                     }
                }
```

Comment: [1] please post your code IN THE QUESTION - wrapped in formatting markers. ///// [2] please post your _complete error text_ IN THE QUESTION - wrapped in formatting markers. ///// [3] have you taken a look at the `try/catch` structure for handling errors?

Comment: I have added the code for the same i am getting error on first line itself in case culture is not registered

Comment: @ShianJA You forgot to answer Lee_Daileys third question.

Comment: Yes i have used it but why to use try if we are just checking whether a value exist or not

Comment: @ShianJA - please check my Answer for an example of the idea of using error handling to deal with your culture check.

Comment: @ShianJA Because the exception is not thrown on your check for `$null`, but already on `[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('gh-es')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what i mean by using `try/catch` to handle an error when checking for a culture ...

```
try {
    [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('666-santa')
    }
    catch
    {
    'something glitched'
    }
```

the output = `something glitched`

without the `try/catch`, the output is an error msg ...

```
Exception calling "GetCultureInfo" with "1" argument(s): "Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
666-santa is an invalid culture identifier."
At line:1 char:1
+ [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('666-santa')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CultureNotFoundException
```